# Memcached causing Web Setup Wizard Error

Tags: magento-2.1, error, session, magento2.1.5, memcached

I have a Magento 2 store that I just configured memcached on.  Everything seemed to be working well and using the guide on the magento site I was able to verify it was working via telnet.

However, when I tried to access the Web Setup Wizard section from the Magento back end I received this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Warning: SessionHandler:1(): open(127.0.0.1:20000/sess_19qiu342pfd61u99a14t054m22, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2) in /home/vanscosu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php on line 22 in /home/vanscosu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(2, 'SessionHandler:...', '/home/vanscosu/...', 22, Array) #1 /home/vanscosu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler/Native.php(22): SessionHandler->read('19qiu342pfd61u9...') #2 /home/vanscosu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SaveHandler.php(93): Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler\Native->read('19qiu342pfd61u9...') #3 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\Session\SaveHandler->read('19qiu342pfd61u9...') #4 /home/vanscosu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php(189): session_start() #5 /home/vanscosu/public_html/var/generation/Magento/Backend/Model/Auth in /home/vanscosu/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61

That is the only thing I've found that doesn't work, but I obviously need it to manage various plugins and extensions.  I've disabled memcached and returned session storage to the file system for now, but I would like to solve this.

Magento 2.1.5
PHP 7.0.19

Answer (score 0):

This issue cause by Web setup wizard not load config from env.php

You can fix this by this ways:

Change php setting on php.ini

```
session.save_handler=memcached
session.save_path=localhost:11211
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento Stack Exchange! Please note that [signatures are removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/295232), especially when they contain links. Such links belong in your profile, if you want to.